# How to record audio while played back by oboe at the same time

Tags: android, oboe

I am using library that uses oboe to play audio and I would like to record it. Is it somehow possible ?

Comment: You could make an request to the owner of the library to allow a callback so that you can obtain the played pcm values each time `onAudioReady` is called and use an encoder like OGG Vorbis to record it to a file. I have done this to successfully, encoded my recorded audio mix into a file. You can also fork the library and implement this functionality. It shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @csguy could you please provide with the library url or something

Answer (score 1):

To do this you'd need access to the data which is being written into the audio stream inside Oboe's `onAudioReady` method. Once you have that you can copy the contents of it into a file.

Comment: Yeah I see something thanks for pointing out I am not sure if this is full answer to this question without any code , but I have some code of oboe recorder and also that lib so  maybe I will do it just thanks to this simple answer .. Will see.

Comment: I wrote a answer around that, using libsndfile library and also capturing the audio in the callback. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77436798/471690